# Angular validation message - override class

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am showing Angular error messages using the following code:

```
<mat-error>
   {{error}}
</mat-error>
```

Sometimes I need to change the left position of the error message. The class that responsible for showing errors is this: ".mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper".I can override it like this:

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
    left: -210px !important;
}
```

Which works. However, it changes error position everywhere. Any idea how to accomplish it?

Thanks

Comment: are you overriding that class style on a component or a global level?

Comment: Component level/

Comment: was the component ViewEncapsulation modified?

Comment: What about a custom class?

Comment: I  tried  something like this: .mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper .customClass {
        left: -210px !important;
    } did not work. Unless I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this **

```
::ngdeep .mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
left: -210px !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

when you use some like

```
<mat-error class="custom">
....
</mat-error>
```

See that the class "custom" is applied to the "mat-error" tag, so you should change some class of this "tag" you can use simple

```
.custom{
  margin-left:-210px;
}
```

If you want more specificy, for example to change the color you can use

```
.custom.mat-mdc-form-field-error {
  margin-left: -40px;
  color: green;
}
```

NOTE: **avoid** use !important, really it's a headache when in a future you will want change a .css if it's full plenty of "importants"